# Accessing a url on Android has different behaviour as compared to when accessing from desktop

Tags: android

I have a url which I could access from a desktop browser without any issue. But when I accessed it from Android, the Http Response is 404.

Any idea what's the issue. I have set the user agent as shown below:

```
final HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, true);
HttpClientParams.setCookiePolicy(params, CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
        
final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20131011 Firefox/23.0");

 final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
       HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

            //check 200 OK for success
     final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
       //how to handle redirects?
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.w("msg", "Error " + statusCode);
             return null;
       }
```

I also tried accessing the URL directly on the Android browser and it also shows 404 error.

Is there any other way doing this?

Comment: can you post your logcat logs?

Comment: @rb512 The logcat logs only shows that the http response is 404, nothing else.

Comment: well, that's because you're just logging the statusCode ( Log.w("msg", "Error " + statusCode);).  can you dump the whole response object there and post the output?

Comment: A wee bit off topic but checkout this library. It provides a nice clean way to do all your HTTP stuff without creating a plethora of objects.

Comment: @rb512 I got something like this: Error org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@414f9a78